# How do I debug `cargo build` hanging at "Updating crates.io index"?

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

My Rust project no longer builds after some conflicts between my RLS plugin and terminal build. I searched around the web and found suggestion of removing my `~/.cargo/registry/index/*`, but after that I can't even build any project.

Now the build always stops at

> Updating crates.io index

Passing in the `--verbose` option doesn't help so I don't even know whether it's dying. What should I do next? How to debug this issue?

Comment: Restore the files you deleted. You **did** remember to back them up before following the advice of a random site on the internet that told you to delete them, right? If you don't have a backup, try deleting all of `~/.cargo`.

Comment: I'm not an expert on cargo, but you could just try reinstalling it, if you don't mind removing `.cargo`.

Comment: You can set `RUST_LOG` to `cargo=debug`: `RUST_LOG=cargo=debug cargo update`. More specific to your problem would be `RUST_LOG=cargo::sources=debug cargo update`.

Comment: I had a different error, and moving my ~/.cargo/registry to a backup at ~/.cargo/registry.backup worked.  Next I did `Cargo build --release` and my project updated my crates.io index.

Comment: I'm having this issue with a clean install, on Windows, on a slow internet connection. Takes ~12 hours. I wonder if this is related to Windows' anti-virus that causes building rust docs to take a while, or the way crates is fetching files. It makes progress, but very very slowly. (incommensurate with the connection speed for other things)

Comment: @qxotk. That didn't work for me. Thanks for sharing your results anyways.

Comment: @rudib That did not work. I uninstalled rust with `rustup self uninstall` and deleted the C:\Users\my_username\.cargo folder and then installed rust again with rust-init.exe

Comment: @Fei Did you find any solution? In my case, it was because github.com was blocked on my system.

Comment: I encountered same problem I deleted .package-cache in .cargo/ . It worked for me you can try It. Take backup first

Comment: @PrajwalDhatwalia I believe it should be bug of the toolset - upgrading to newer version of rust fixed that.

Comment: It seems clear here that, unless somebody knows otherwise, cargo is missing a facility to provide debugging output for network activity. If you monitor network activity in some other manner, such as via `strace -f cargo update` or running tcpdump or wireshark, for me it seems the delay was relating to the network. You can also monitor the git files it is trying to work with using `pv -d CARGO_PID` or `ls -l /proc/CARGO_PID/fd`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delete the `~/.cargo/.package-cache` file.

Comment: Ran into this in 2024 and this was the fix. Any thoughts on what gets messed up with the cache that this solves it?

Comment: @IT_User `Cargo` seems to wait before starting a program until file `.package-cache` has been deleted after loading all libraries. Presumably, race conditions occasionally prevent this. If I knew the exact reason, I would comment on it in my reply.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend **not wiping any folders**, as the active data is a git repository with some cryptographic registry data, and the common cause is network issues communicating with GitHub. Whether the problem is simply a slow connection or worsely compromised infrastructure, wiping the folder could remove correct data you have already downloaded that would then be redownloaded through the nonresponsive link. If the problem is local data corruption, then wiping the folder would make sense.

It sounds like cargo is missing an important logging facility for git network activity, unless somebody more familiar with it knows further.

Here is how I diagnosed this without knowledge of cargo. It seems it would be faster if the user knew about the cargo registry.

```
# ran failing process in background
$ cargo update &
     Updating crates.io index
[1] 8129

# store PID of background process in variable
$ CARGO_PID=$1

# listed files accessed by process
# the one of note is the git pack file
$ ls -l /proc/$CARGO_PID/fd
total 0
lrwx------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 0 -> /dev/pts/377
lrwx------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 1 -> /dev/pts/377
lrwx------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 10 -> 'socket:[45370067]'
lrwx------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 11 -> 'socket:[45383920]'
lrwx------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 2 -> /dev/pts/377
lrwx------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 3 -> /home/user/.cargo/.package-cache
lr-x------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 4 -> /home/user/.cargo/registry/index/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/.git/objects/pack/pack-4bac04bfb4c5de794c1dd0a40d86cfc18f9eb5ae.pack
lrwx------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 5 -> 'socket:[45370061]'
lr-x------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 6 -> /home/user/.pki/nssdb/cert9.db
lr-x------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 7 -> /home/user/.pki/nssdb/key4.db
lr-x------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 8 -> /etc/pki/nssdb/cert9.db
lr-x------. 1 user user 64 Nov  7 06:19 9 -> /etc/pki/nssdb/key4.db

# it's working with a git repository, visited git repository
$ cd /home/user/.cargo/registry/index/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/.git

# i then looked various common places for the remote it was fetching from.
# FETCH_HEAD showed this in one run, but in another FETCH_HEAD was empty
# I then found it in the logs folder.
# you could also use a network utility, strace, or debug or patch cargo
$ cat config
[core]
    bare = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = true
    logallrefupdates = true
$ ls
config  description  FETCH_HEAD  HEAD  hooks  info  logs  objects  refs
$ cat HEAD
ref: refs/heads/main
$ cat FETCH_HEAD
$ ls logs
refs
$ ls logs/refs/
remotes
$ ls logs/refs/remotes/
origin
$ ls logs/refs/remotes/origin/
HEAD
$ cat logs/refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 cd2e0d3249278088bdb2c8ab9227c1e745977d2a John Doe <johndoe@example.com> 1671547379 -0500   fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
cd2e0d3249278088bdb2c8ab9227c1e745977d2a 995b889318272a6dbc9591a688fc6d0053fbdacf John Doe <johndoe@example.com> 1671550295 -0500   fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
995b889318272a6dbc9591a688fc6d0053fbdacf e6ca1cbd89a020cfccfb741738b47d905ec51a38 John Doe <johndoe@example.com> 1671965624 -0500   fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
e6ca1cbd89a020cfccfb741738b47d905ec51a38 9dfcadd951ddd8b5b311b0653bf09069b62594a3 John Doe <johndoe@example.com> 1672045603 -0500   fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
9dfcadd951ddd8b5b311b0653bf09069b62594a3 2df4156cfe1fba11c11f8b1956ac8c3012da94da John Doe <johndoe@example.com> 1672051948 -0500   fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
2df4156cfe1fba11c11f8b1956ac8c3012da94da 53c0024ba8565070cc0644cc4417d81e2d588aac John Doe <johndoe@example.com> 1672324569 -0500   fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
53c0024ba8565070cc0644cc4417d81e2d588aac 2bdf23bbb3e8e1752ab88485168330751d8d9e49 John Doe <johndoe@example.com> 1683666817 -0400   fetch https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
```

Now (if you scroll way to the bottom right above) one can see that it is likely hanging performing a `git fetch` from `https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index`.

```
# terminate background process
$ fg
cargo update    (wd: ~/src/project)
^C

# try fetching from its url
$ git fetch --progress --verbose https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index
POST git-upload-pack (117 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (958 bytes)
POST git-upload-pack (967 bytes)
remote: Enumerating objects: 626476, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (35613/35613), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1310/1310), done.
Receiving objects:  98% (615100/626476), 399.19 MiB | 1.36 MiB/s
# hangs at 98%, no more output
```

The troubleshooting has simplified to diagnosing a git fetch from this repository.

Personally, my dmesg then started spewing errors regarding my wifi driver, perhaps an unfortunate coincidence or alternatively an indication of malicious activity. More commonly, my available disk space was getting very low, and I was having network issues communicating with github.com .

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 I/O operation timed out
error: 4611 bytes of body are still expected
fetch-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
fatal: early EOF
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

Answer (score -2):

Change cargo source in ~/.cargo/config. This works for me.

For example:

```
[source.crates-io]
registry = "https://github.com/rust-lang/crates.io-index"
replace-with = 'ustc'

[source.ustc]
registry = "git://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/crates.io-index"
```

Comment: This looks suspicious. You should at least explain that this sends cargo requests to a server based in China, so it might help with firewall issues from within China but not for users outside of China.