# cargo build freezes when building opencv-rust

Tags: opencv, rust

It's been stuck on `Building [=======================> ] 753/758: opencv(build)` for a couple of days now. I'm on `ubuntu 22.04`. Rust version is

```
rustc 1.72.0 (5680fa18f 2023-08-23)
binary: rustc
commit-hash: 5680fa18feaa87f3ff04063800aec256c3d4b4be
commit-date: 2023-08-23
host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
release: 1.72.0
LLVM version: 16.0.5
```

I'm using `opencv-rust` version `0.83.0`

`libopencv-dev`, `libclang-dev`, `clang` are already installed. I am fairly new to rust and don't have much context on how to debug this. Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably, it is because of https://github.com/twistedfall/opencv-rust/issues/480

Comment: Thanks! This helped. Can you submit this as an answer?

Comment: Usually the [underlying problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361052/how-do-i-debug-cargo-build-hanging-at-updating-crates-io-index/72842161?r=SearchResults&s=66%7C8.9013#72842161) in similar cases is that the `.package-cache` file was not deleted.

Answer (score 0):

Probably fixed by this, based on the limited information provided:

```ini
[patch.crates-io]
cc = { git = "https://github.com/rust-lang/cc-rs.git", version = "1.0", tag = "1.0.79" }
```